# Delete 2 yrs old inventory from csv and relevant individual folders

Tags: powershell-3.0

Please kindly help I am totally new to powershell and am needing help deleting old inventory from csv and related folders.
I have details as follows in the csv file:
Inv code, Inventory name, Date Entered

I have to run a function to look up the cvs file in a directory and any inventory that is older than 2 yrs, to go delete the entry from the csv file and in the same directory to delete the relevant inventory code folder.

Let's say I have:
Inv code / Inventory Name / Date Entered
MSPN001 / Metal Spoon / 2/15/2006

The same inventory has a folder in the directory that contains details of the inventory such as first batch, quantity, returns etc...;.
Folder name is according to the Inv Code in the cvs file, so for the above would be:
MSPN001

I need the function to look up only the ones older than 2 years and delete.

Sorry I am still in the learning phase and due to a colleague on long term leave I had to learn and do this.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us in code what you've tried so far.

Comment: how look your cvs file? Can you post it ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSV looks like this:

```
Inv Code,Inventory Name,DateEntered
MSPN001,Metal Spoon,2/15/2006
```

You just need to create your variable to get a date 2 years from whenever you're running the script, which roughly is subtracting 730 days:

```
$2yrs = (Get-Date).AddDays(-(730))
```

Next, you want another variable which loads the `$2yr` variable and formats it to your date format:

```
$OldData = $2yrs.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Your `$Filename` variable is whatever your CSV is called:

```
$Filename = "Inventory.csv"
```

Now just import the CSV, and have it find any lines where the data for the header `Date Entered` is an older date than your limitation of 2 years ago, and export it back to your existing CSV:

```
(Import-Csv $Filename) | Where{$_.'Date Entered' -lt $OldData} | Export-Csv $Filename -NoTypeInformation
```

Granted, OP will never be back to this topic, I imagine, if he didn't have time to post his CSV format, but just in case someone else needs this in the future.